# Proof of 2D-LOTUS in the discrete case

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, expected-value

I am self-learning probability theory from *Introduction to Probability theory and its applications*, by Feller. I would like to ask, if this is a technically correct proof of 2D-LOTUS (Law of the Unconscious statistician) in the discrete case.

---

**Theorem**. Let $X,Y$ be a pair of random variables and let $Z = g(X,Y)$ be a function of $X,Y$. The mathematical expectation of $Z$ is given by,

\begin{align*}
E[g(X,Y)] = \sum_{x}\sum_y g(x,y) f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\end{align*}

where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint mass function of $X,Y$.

---

**Proof(My attempt)**.

\begin{align*}
E[g(X,Y)] &= \sum_x \sum_y g(X(\omega),Y(\omega))P(Z=g(X(\omega),Y(\omega)))\\
&= \sum_x \sum_y \left[\sum_{\omega:X(\omega)=x}\left\{\sum_{\omega:Y(\omega)=y}g(X(\omega),Y(\omega)) \cdot P\{\omega\}\right\}\right] \\
& \{\text{ Iterating over }\omega \}\\
&=\sum_x \sum_y g(x,y)\left[\sum_{\omega:X(\omega)=x}\left\{\sum_{\omega:Y(\omega)=y}P\{\omega\}\right\}\right] \\
&\{ g(x,y) \text{ is a constant in the inner sum }\}\\
&=\sum_x \sum_y g(x,y) \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\end{align*}

Comment: No, a correct proof should use the theory of [integrals with image measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#:~:text=In%20measure%20theory%2C%20a%20discipline,another%20using%20a%20measurable%20function.).

Comment: @Snoop, I am yet to learn any Measure and Integration theory yet.